# Can't embed a Python script that imports tensorflow in a C program that is linked against libtensorflow

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am in the process of creating a C program that is linked to tensorflow C api. Within this C program, a Python script is called in which it uses TensorFlow to train an ANN model.The ANN model is saved in a local directory, end the C program will load the ANN and use it to calculate something.

Here's a snippet of my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "ontheflysurrogate.h"
#include "tensorflow/c/c_api.h"

typedef struct  /*Struct to store neccesary ANN session properties*/
{
    TF_Session* Session;
    TF_Graph* Graph;
    TF_Status* Status;
    TF_SessionOptions* SessionOpts;
    TF_Buffer* RunOpts;
}Session_Props;

char* trainingANN(char*, char*, int);
void *load_session(char*);

int main()
{ 
     char* filepath_training = "/home/abc/def/training_data.csv";
     char* path_ANN_eta_PB = trainingANN(filepathtraining_eta_PB,prefixres,count);
     Session_props* sess = load_session(path_ANN_eta_PB);
     return 1;
}

char* trainingANN(char* filepathtrainingdata, char* prefixres, int count);
{
     /*Call a python script within which it imports tensorflow here!*/
     
     return saved_model_path;
}

void *load_session(char* saved_model_dir)
{
    //***************Adjust the logging of tensorflow by setting a variable 
    //***************in the environment called TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL
    char *var = "TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=0";
    int ret;
    ret = putenv(var);

    //***************Allocate dynamic memory from the heap for Session_Props data struct 
    Session_Props *sess = malloc(sizeof(Session_Props));

    //***************Instantiate Session Properties
    TF_Graph* Graph = TF_NewGraph(); TF_Status* Status = TF_NewStatus();
    TF_SessionOptions* SessionOpts = TF_NewSessionOptions(); TF_Buffer* RunOpts = NULL;

    const char* tags = "serve"; int ntags = 1;

    TF_Session* Session = TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel
    (
        SessionOpts, 
        RunOpts, 
        saved_model_dir, 
        &tags, 
        ntags, 
        Graph, 
        NULL, 
        Status
    );
    
    //***************************Populate the struct
    sess->Graph = Graph; sess->Session = Session; sess->Status = Status;
    sess->SessionOpts = SessionOpts; sess->RunOpts = RunOpts;

    return sess;
}
```

However, I keep getting this fatal error saying that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/philgun/Documents/codecodecode/codecodecode/GSL_Project/ANN.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
ImportError: No module named tools
Failed to load "ANN"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/philgun/Documents/codecodecode/codecodecode/GSL_Project/ANN.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/audio/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.gen_audio_ops import decode_wav
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py", line 9, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf7Message11GetTypeNameEv


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have tried to look into https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7541 and also https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20561 . I tried to build TensorFlow pip package from the source using bazel just like what's written in the TF Github. I also tried to follow https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20561 discussion and tried to implement each one of the suggestions, but I can't make it work.

Here's my tensorflow link flags, called from python 2.7

```
>>> tensorflow.sysconfig.get_link_flags()
['-L/home/philgun/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core', '-l:libtensorflow_framework.so.2']
```

One thing I can't understand is it seems my Python 2 is missing this file

```
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
```

while it exists in my python 3, even though I installed TensorFlow using pip:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

and also building from the source for Python 2.

At the moment I am running out of ideas on how to work around this problem, any idea will be very appreciated!

Cheers,
PG

Comment: You **do** have the wrapper file. I do not know **what** you have done, bcause you said "even though I installed TensorFlow using pip: and also building from the source for Python 2." - I presume you cannot do **both**.

Comment: And how do you run your python script? In fact, how is the C program even relevant to the question?

Comment: Hi Anti thanks for the comment. I run the python script from within the C program where I import the python module and call a specific function from within the module. I use this guide https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/embedding.html which is quite straight forward and easy to be implemented I presume. What I meant by "installing TF using pip and then build it from the source" is that I did install TF using pip, I encountered this error, I uninstalled TF, and tried to build it from the source which didn't solve my problem.

Comment: (cont'd) --> The relevancy of the C program: If the C program doesn't include any function that utilise the C_API of TF, then everything went smooth. If I include functions that utilise C_API, then the error comes up. It seems that it doesn't allow me to use tensorflow C API along side python tensorflow package. The error comes when the python script tries to import tensorflow. Somehow, the tensorflow C API is confilcting with the importing process of tensorflow within the python script

Comment: So if you're **embedding** then it is relevant to clarify that you indeed are **embedding*

Comment: Hi Anti yeah I think I have put it in the title that I can't embed my python within the C program. So anyway, do you have any idea?